# How to prove that partial derivatives exist at (0,0)

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

> Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$  be defined by $ f(x,y) = \frac{xy} {x^2 +y^2}$ if $(x,y )\neq (0,0)$ and $f(0,0) = 0.$ Prove that $\frac{ \partial f} {\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f} {\partial y}$ exists at (0,0).

I found derivatives at general $(x,y)$ and got them as

$\frac{ \partial f} {\partial x}= \frac{x^2y +y^3 -2x^2y} { (x^2+y^2)^2}$

$\frac{\partial f} {\partial y}=\frac{x^3 +xy^2 -2xy^2}{ (x^2+y^2)^2}$, but I am not sure how should I prove that partial derivative exists at (0,0).In case , I have to negate the existence  near $(0,0)$ then I try to find some curve of form $y=m x^k$ where $k$ is some chosen power. But How to do it in case of proving continuous.

Comment: Just apply the definition of the partial derivatives at the origin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition, how else?
$$ \lim _{h\to 0} \frac{f(0+h,0) - f(0,0)}{h} = \lim _{h\to 0} \frac{\frac{0h}{h^2}}{h} = 0, $$
which implies $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}f(0,0) = 0$. The map $f$ is smooth outside the origin, so the partial derivatives also exist outside the origin. But that does not mean they necessarily exist at the origin.